# Use if __name__ == '__main__': for tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

When you write some scripts that are self sufficient, is it a bad idea to use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` as a place to write tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test logic and tests should never be part of "production" (production can mean in use by you, released to client, etc.) code. So, it is a bad idea to have them *anywhere* within your script.

Ideally, have them in separate files.

Comment: @MattJoiner Because such tests aren't meant to be run in production. They are meant to aid in development. A test failing in user's environment does absolutely nothing apart from breaking the application. That said, there are legitimate ways of using "sanity" assertions inside the production code, that help in getting early feedback (i.e. application can say "hey, this code is broken", before the execution actually gets to that part of the code).

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on your code and purposes of your script.  For big and complex projects you for sure have to put all your tests into a separate place.

But while working on something small it might be a good solution to have tests along with code - it is the main idea of [`doctest`](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) (it is a great Python module that allows you to write tests in the docstrings).  In this case your `if __name__ == '__main__'` will look like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I find it nice and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to put the tests in separate units that use the unittest module. This separation allows you to keep the main code clean (no need for lots of testing helper functions) and encourages you to write good comprehensive tests since you are not inhibited by cluttering the main code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, in fact, I saw a lot of python scripts (mostly plugins of another application) written that way.